# minimalistic 'sed' shall perform as "regular" sed. Need help parsing

Tags: sed

I am using a script that parses JSON. I know, I know, you should never do it. But the script makes use of it a lot. And thats why it runs into trouble. 
I am using it on BusyBox and theres only a minimalistic version of sed.

THis is where it runs into trouble. This is the JSON output:

```
{"expires": "Thu, 11 Oct 2012 11:30:29 +0000", "upload_id": "hhgJHflih753jDhhod", "offset": 293876}
```

This is the sed command used to get the value for "offset" which worls on busybox:

```
sed -n -e 's/.*"offset":\s*\([^}]*\).*/\1/p'
```

This is the command to get upload_id, which does not work on BusyBox:

```
sed -n -e 's/.*"upload_id":\s*"*\([^"]*\)"*.*/\1/p'
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me make it work to get "upload_id" on the BusyBox with the minimalistic sed.
Thanks!

Comment: Do the lines always contain these elements in this order?

Comment: Yes, they're always in the same order.

Comment: Then one of the simple solutions in the answers should be enough.

Comment: I installed a package with the "original" GNU sed.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`cut`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cut-invocation.html):

```
$ # get upload_id
$ echo '{"expires": "Thu, 11 Oct 2012 11:30:29 +0000", "upload_id": "hhgJHflih753jDhhod", "offset": 293876}' |\
cut -d'"' -f8
hhgJHflih753jDhhod
$ # get offset
$ echo '{"expires": "Thu, 11 Oct 2012 11:30:29 +0000", "upload_id": "hhgJHflih753jDhhod", "offset": 293876}' |\
cut -d':' -f6 | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d'}' -f1
293876
```

This is as minimalistic as it gets.

**Edit:**

Using [`gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/):

```
$ echo '{"expires": "Thu, 11 Oct 2012 11:30:29 +0000", "upload_id": "hhgJHflih753jDhhod", "offset": 293876}' |\
gawk -F'"' '{print $8}'       
hhgJHflih753jDhhod
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk -F "[:,]" '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /upload_id/) { gsub(/[" {}]/,"",$(i+1)); print $(i+1) } }' file.txt
```

Result:

```
hhgJHflih753jDhhod
```

Note that this will work for the `offset` and `upload_id` fields, but not the `expires` field. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

grep:

```
grep -Po '(?<=upload_id": ")[^"]*'
```

sed:

```
sed -r 's/.*upload_id": "([^"]*).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Does busybox support `GNU grep`'s `-P` flag?